# Product Page View Blank For Some Products

Tags: magento-1.9, product-view

So if you take a look at this page:

http://www.butterfliesbridal.co.uk/wedding/mother-of-the-bride/70825.html

You will notice that the product page view.phtml seems to be blank, however if I go to the category page and click on some other products the view displays. Any idea why this might be happening?

So far I have tried a re-index and reset my cache.

Comment: Could you pls explain brief how did you solve the error?

Comment: I am getting the same issue, how can I find what is the issue? There is no console error and log error even view page source also empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you view the source for the product that errors out, you'll see this error at the end:

```
Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 2160001 bytes) in
/home/butterfl/public_html/lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php on line 246
```

The error is in the GD library right where your images are output.  You'll need to either increase PHP's memory limit or look at the images for that product and make sure you aren't trying to process a huge image (I'd look here first as other products are working).

Comment: Thanks so much I didn't know that the errors displayed in the source code :)

Comment: Yeah, sometimes if it breaks in the middle of an html element as was this case it won't show on the rendered screen.